# Растр vs вектор = посоветуйте

Tags: wpf

Здравствуйте. Есть программа которая открывает большие растровые изображения с чертежами(в развернутом виде до 300мб), изображение часто масштабируется и передвигается мышью (аля графический редактор). Смущает низкая производительность и нестабильность работы (иногда подвисает, почему пока так и не нашел). Сейчас работаю над тем чтобы открывать чертежи в векторе. Смогу ли я от этого выиграть ? Чертежи очень большие, в них будет много элементов. Или лучше вернутся к растру и пытаться делать работу программы стабильней ?

Comment: профайлером пробовали?

Comment: профайлером неосилил, работа ведется на виртуальной машине, а он там почему то процесса не видит. Хотя сомневаюсь что поможет - зависания несистематичные. Бывает виснет после 2й смены изображения, а бывает более 30 смен изображения выдерживает.

Comment: Хм. Вы бы не отлаживали тяжёлую графику на виртуальной машине. Нет, правда. WPF может применить аппаратное ускорение при доступе к нормальной, а не эмулированной видеокарте.

Comment: @gordec есть старый анекдот о том, как водитель пытается оживить машину, а мальчик ему:

    -- А я знаю, что у тебя не работает
    -- Что?
    -- Машина!

Причин может быть масса, и здесь проблему Вам вряд ли помогут решить. Просто по формату форума.

(Например у А. Картера (см.http://progstone.ru/ )  есть пример, как для геодезической или географической системы оказалось убийственным бездумное использование ООП. Вопрос "вектр/растр" в том случае ничего бы не решал).

Comment: видеокарта как раз эмулирована, но это особо не мешает. Ведь потом прога активно тестируется на нормальных машинах.

Comment: А вы профилировали? Если у вас пересчёт вида выполняется в UI-потоке, конечно, будет тормозить.

Вы бы отпрофилировали тяжёлую операцию.

Comment: Я понял. Придется переносить проект домой. На работе на вирт машине профилирование почемуто не работает.

Comment: @gordec фтопку сисадмина! Всегда был противником бездумной виртуализации

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вектор вам не даст выигрыша в отображении. Отображать выгоднее растр - быстрее и все такое. Вектор дает выигрыш в хранении, передаче и удобнее масштабировать.

Возьмите любой профессиональный пакет векторной графики (Corel, AutoCAD) и увидите, что скорость отображения это его слабое место.

Comment: тогда принцип оставлю тот-же. Полотно оставлю растр, а слои поверх в векторе. Тогда нужно искать причину зависаний, спасибо за совет

Comment: >> Отображать выгоднее растр - быстрее и все такое.

Мне почему то всегда казалось, что вектор быстрее будет рендерится. Разве нет ?

Comment: Запусти в CorelDraw сложный вектор и сравни со скоростью разворачивания любого растра - разница видна невооруженным глазом

Comment: да с масштабированием пришлось мудрить. Пришлось делать несколько копий изображения с разным разрешением и подвязывать их под определенные границы масштаба. У меня в программе чаще всего происходит движение(смещение) изображения в сторону, на втором месте масштабирование, ну и реже полная смена изображения - хотя и это происходит не редко. Вот ищу компромисс. Наткнулся в процессе на непонятные зависания в процессе смены изображения - отладчик студии ошибок не видит, просто виснет и запускается отладчик (устранение проблем)винды. Теперь придется вплотную искать проблему.

Comment: @gordec Попробуйте [двойную буферизацию](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b367a457(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: а есть ли двойная буфферизация в wpf как таковая ? То что по ссылке помоему касается только Windows Form